# FSA Gossamer Crank Spider cracked

Tags: crankset, crack

I've got an FSA Gossamer pro MegaExo compact crank set.  Lately, while tightening the bolts on the crank spider, it cracked (see picture).  I know FSA has recalled the left crank because it turned out to crack for the same reason.  Has anyone had the same problem with his right crank?  Does FSA sell spare parts?

[image: spider crack]

Comment: Left crank does not have a spider to crack - how can it be "recalled for the same reason". Suggest you take the part back to the place of purchase and discuss with them. FSA is a reputable brand, I expect they would replace a faulty part.

Comment: Yes, but it has mounting holes as well.  This is from the recall notice "Full
Speed Ahead (FSA) has received reports that the bolt shoulder on the non-drive Gossamer BB30 series crankarms can
crack and break if the installer exceeds the recommended torque specification while tightening the crankbolt."

Comment: -1 Because the question is more of a rant than a valid question.

Comment: I did not mean to rant.  I'm very happy with all the FSA components. They perform extraordinarily well in terms of transmission efficiency and directness. Just wondered whether the crack was related to the recall notice.

Comment: @artistoex FYI it's generally bad form to call out people for down-voting a question. See: (http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/748/if-you-are-going-to-downvote-why-not-add-feedback-as-to-why-you-downvoted) It is better to ask for constructive criticism or input on how to improve a question.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off getting on the phone to FSA as opposed to asking your questions here. If it's a common problem they'll be the ones to know and they'll likely be eager to set it right.

I can tell you that I've had no such problems with my Gossamer cranks in many years of ownership. If I were to speculate I would say that that is a defect and if the cranks aren't ancient (which they don't appear to be given your BB style) the manufacturer may well cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Windwave Distribution are the UK returns contact for FSA, among others. You could give them a call, i'm sure they could help: http://www.windwave.co.uk/index.html